# How to upgrade Fedora Core 3?

Tags: fedora, yum

I want to upgrade from fedora core 3 to latest release without using a cd. I have internet connection.

Is it possible to use `yum` to upgrade the OS entirely to the latest version? At present there are no `.repo` files in my `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory. So I could not use the `yum` command.

How to get the necessary repository and to upgrade the OS?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what's wrong with the DVD? It's way cleaner, not to mention easier...

Comment: The files in the system will be lost in a fresh install. Are'nt they @nico?

Comment: I think this will be difficult for a release so old. You could upgrade through all the intervening releases, but that would be prohibitively time consuming. I think you would be better off backing up all your config files (using all files in /etc and files in /home and possibly data files in other locations) and reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: depends on how your system is set up. I have different partitions for `/`, `home`, `media` (photos and music) etc etc. In this way if I upgrade I keep things like home and media and documents and just wipe the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using yum is feasible for such an early release of Fedora. I seem to remember having trauma upgrading an FC4 system. My best advice is to:

1. Download and burn a DVD of the latest version of Fedora.
2. Backup any important user files as Faheem suggests.
3. Start the installation process (reboot from the DVD).
4. At the boot prompt use the 'upgrade' option.

This will attempt to upgrade your system without affecting your user files. If this fails, you'll need to do a fresh installation and re-install your backed up files.

For later versions of Fedora, using yum is much better supported:

```
yum install preupgrade
preupgrade
```

This will download the correct versions of all the RPMs required and set everything up so that the system can upgrade itself when it reboots.